# Changing connection string for different Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My application used Code first approach & Entity Framework 6.0.

My requirement is that when a `User A` logs in connection string `AppSchema` should be used for whole application & when `User B` logs in connection string `AppSchema1` should be used. My application is very big, i want to achieve this from a central location.

Below is the code :-

Connection String :-

```
 <add name="AppSchema" connectionString="Data Source=Server1\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=MSchema;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Connection String 2 :-

```
<add name="AppSchema1" connectionString="Data Source=Server1\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=MSchema;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

ApplicationDbContext :-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider, IDisposable
{
     public ApplicationDbContext(string schemaname)
                : base("AppSchema")
            {            
                SchemaName = schemaname;
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
            }
}
```

Use :-

```
 using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
    {
        ....
        ctx.tblEmployee.Add(mod);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: First connect your parent database then through the boolean tag you will differentiate your users which database should use.

Comment: If the database connection string is selected based on user, where do you get the users from? Doesn't this approach mean something is wrong in the design?

Comment: if you looking for saas like application, check out multi tenant architecture with different schema for each tenant ! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Overload the DbContext's constructor with the name of a connection string.

```
 public class ExampleDBContext : DbContext
    {
    public ExampleDBContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : 
       base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

pass the name of a configured connection string or a connection string when you instantiate your DbContext.

```
  var context = new ExampleDBContext ( "set name Or ConnectionString in run time");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one static method which return connection string schema name. For example:

```
Public static String GetSchema()
{
string schemaName;
var userName=Session["UserName"];
switch (userName)
    {
    case "User A":
        schemaName="AppSchema";
        break;
        case "User B":
            schemaName="AppSchema1";
        break;
        default:
            schemaName="DefaultSchema";
}

return schemaName;
}
```

Call this Method like

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(SomeClassName.GetSchema()))
{
    ....
    ctx.tblEmployee.Add(mod);
}
```

Comment: I hope you won't get many of those special cases. It will be a pretty big switch otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbModelCacheKeyProvider, IDisposable
{
        public ApplicationDbContext(string connection)
            : base(connection)
        {            
            ...
        }
```

}

and to create DbContext object

```
var connection = GetDbConnectionByUser(string user);
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(connection))
{
    ....
}
```

and whatever logic suitable to your structure for differentiating connection string by user

```
public string GetDbConnectionByUser(string user)
{

}
```

If you can spend some more time to improve, see the [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)